# Manipulating a file using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have the following file:

```
RATL_EXTRAFLAGS := -DRATL_REDHAT -DRATL_VENDOR_VER=601 -DRATL_EXTRA_VER=0
LINUX_KERNEL_DIR=/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build
CONFIG_MVFS=m
```

Assuming that the file name is `testFile`
I'd like to know how get the value of `LINUX_KERNEL_DIR` and how can I change it in case I need?

Another thing how can I check what is the value of `-DRATL_VENDOR_VER` and also how can I change the value in case I need to do that?

I'll prefer to get an answer using `sed`.

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Looked up related questions about `sed`? Stack Overflow is not a place where you ask people to write your code...

Comment: Yes i've tried with `awk` but it's not really working. i know how to get the line number and than replcae the string but i can't be sure that the structure of this file will be the same, i mean that the line numbers will be the same

Comment: Post whatever attempt you've made; it demonstrates that you've at least made an effort towards a solution and that you're not just waiting for someone to do your work for you. If "it's not really working", explain *what* exactly is not working.

Comment: You write that you "can't be sure that the structure of this file will be the same". However, you need to be crystal-clear what the general structure of the file is, if you expect to get a definite answer.

Comment: i've tried something like this `sed -n '/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR=*/p' $file` but it's not printing the value of `LINUX_KERNEL_DIR`

Comment: That should be: `sed -n '/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR=/p' "$file"`

Comment: the thing is that it's printing the whole line how can i just print the value after sign `=`

Comment: ok i found a way to print just value : `sed -n -e '/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR/ s/.*\= *//p' $file`

Comment: how can i print the value of `DRATL_VENDOR_VER` this one is tricky,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F= '$1=="LINUX_KERNEL_DIR"{print $2}' "$file"
/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build
```

This `awk` command sets input field separator as `=` so that text before `=` can be accessed using `$1` and value after `=` using `$2`. When `$1 == "LINUX_KERNEL_DIR"` it prints `$2`.

Based on your comments you can do:

```
awk -F '[= ]' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) if($i=="-DRATL_VENDOR_VER") { print $(i+1); break}}
    $1=="LINUX_KERNEL_DIR"{print $2}' file
601
/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build
```

Comment: What about the value `DRATL_VENDOR_VER` , how can i print it ?

Answer (score 2):

This will yield the value of `LINUX_KERNEL_DIR` using sed as you preferred:

```
sed -n '/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR/p' testFile | sed 's/.*=//'
```

Also, if you want the value of `-DRATL_VENDOR_VER`:

```
sed -n '/-DRATL_VENDOR_VER/p' testFile | sed 's/.*DRATL_VENDOR_VER=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/g'
```

Moreover, if you want to change the value of, for example, `LINUX_KERNEL_DIR`, you can use this script:

```
file=$1
pattern=$(sed -n '/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR/p' $file | sed 's/.*=//')
sed s,$pattern,whatever, $file
```

The same procedure works  if you want to change the value of `DRATL_VENDOR_VER`, all you have to change is the `pattern` variable.

Be aware, if the variable `pattern` contains backslashes, you need to use a different separator in your sed command, in this case I used `,`

Comment: sed is not designed for extracting values, it's better to use awk or grep

Answer (score 2):

**To print  the value in `LINUX_KERNEL_DIR`**

```
sed -n '/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR/s/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR=//p' testFile
```

this find the line that has the pattern `LINUX_KERNEL_DIR` and then deletes `"LINUX_KERNEL_DIR/s/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR="` and as a result only the value is output

**To print the value of `DRATL_VENDOR_VER`**

```
sed -n '/RATL_EXTRAFLAGS/s/.*-DRATL_VENDOR_VER=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' testFile
```

**To print both of the above values at the same time**

```
sed -n '/RATL_EXTRAFLAGS/s/.*-DRATL_VENDOR_VER=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p;/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR/s/LINUX_KERNEL_DIR=//p' testFile
```

**To change the value of `DRATL_VENDOR_VER`**

```
sed -i '/RATL_EXTRAFLAGS/s/-DRATL_VENDOR_VER=[0-9]*/-DRATL_VENDOR_VER=YOUR_VALUE_HERE/g'  testFile
```

where `YOUR_VALUE_HERE` represents your value.